# How to customize comment character in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to write AT&T X86 assembly language in a file with `.s` file extension, the default comment character for me is `;`, but my assembler needs `#` as a comment character.

I have to type `#` manually, which is so annoying.

---

There's another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853163/how-do-i-customize-comment-characters-in-vs-code) with the same statement in Stack Overflow, but it doesn't help.

---

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [this extension](https://github.com/13xforever/x86_64-assembly-vscode), you can go into its vscode extension folder (on Windows it's `C:\Users\USERNAME\.vscode\extensions\` then search for `13xforever` and open `language-configuration.json` and you can change the line that says

```json
"lineComment": ";"
```

to

```json
"lineComment": "#"
```

Afterwards VSCode must be restarted.