# How to change the default comment character in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments

While writing a comment in `.ini` files, VS Code gives me the comment `;` when what I need is a `#`. Is there a setting somewhere where I can replace that character?

This is similar issue but not a duplicate of the following post, as I am not editing assembly and the extension provided does not work:
[How to customize comment character in Visual Studio Code?](https://superuser.com/questions/1476090/how-to-customize-comment-character-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: You would have to modify `package.json` from that extension in order to achieve what you want.

Comment: I tried multiple .ini editors.  Sadly, none of them have such a setting in their package.json

Comment: Ok; Apparently you didn’t understand.  You would have to edit the package.json, and the .ini file to the list of file extensions, then modify the other .json file to define the comment character.

Comment: That worked! So to reiterate, I needed to:
1) Install https://github.com/13xforever/x86_64-assembly-vscode
2) Find the extension under ~/.vscode/extensions
3) Modify package.json to include .ini under extensions.
4) Modify language-configuration.json, under lineComment replace ";" with "#"

Thank you Ramhound for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way around this I've found is to associate .ini files with Shell Script instead of Ini - then you can toggle comments using '#'.

Do Ctrl+Shift+P, Change Language Mode, then Configure File Association for '.ini', and select Shell Script.

Comment: Changing the language mode to a `shellscript` loses all the other formatting goodness.  Not terribly helpful.

Comment: Brain, thank you so much!  This is better than my previous solution as something updated and it stopped working.

Answer (score 2):

As noted [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116729#issuecomment-783423091), change the language mode to *Properties* rather than *Ini*.  Look in the status bar to see whether the language is "Ini" (lineComment `;`) or "Properties" (lineComment `#`).

Comment: I still get `;` when setting _Properties_

Answer (score 1):

1. the `;` for `[ini]` and the `#` for `[properties]` seems to be just as expected, as [the existed answer](https://superuser.com/a/1757622/1479214) says
2. seems that the `lineComment` char not works properly in some version of vscode ... I tested the v1.84.1 on flatpak and v1.84.2 on windows is fine ~
3. if still not work, just [try the extension `ArturoDent.custom-language-syntax`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77527631/7860292)